# how to change all the label tags from one file

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I have a web application where I have used `mustache.js`. Now I need to be able to change all the text labels from one common file. Suppose I have a "start"  button and I need to change this "start" text to "you can start" and similarly for all other html text labels, so that I don't need to go to the individual `mustache` files to make the changes.

So how can I put all the texts in one file so that I can make changes from only that file? Please help.

Comment: This is painful to read. First off, please start to use spaces after a full stop. Please provide more and concise information like code snippets and elaborate on what you have already tried and failed with.

Comment: Lots of ways to solve this... in any case, whatever is calling Mustache is going to have to pass the language file data.

Comment: @Brad ....can you please explain one way to solve this.

Comment: @abhilekh Have whatever is calling Mustache pass the language file data.  I couldn't give you a more specific answer without seeing your code.